# Verifiable computation examples where verification is much faster than re-execution

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, verifiability, snarks

[Verifiable computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_computing) (VC) has been practical since [Pinocchio](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/279.pdf) and the field has evolved significantly since.
What are some of the best examples today where computation is significantly faster than the verification, for VC to make sense? Are there examples where computation is astronomically slow, but verification is lightning fast?